# C# Splitting strings randomly

Tags: c#, string, random

I have a string like this:

```
string str = "ABCDEFGHI"
```

I want a result like:

```
string str1 = "AB";
string str2 = "CDEF";
string str3 = "G";
string str4 = "HI";
```

The idea is to randomly partitioning a string into a sequence of substring with random length.

I've tried the following:

```
public static string SplitString(string input)
    {
        string result = "";
        int j = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
        {
            Random random = new Random();
            j = random.Next(i+1, input.Length);
            string subString = input.Substring(i,j); //ERROR
            i = j-1;
            Console.WriteLine("New substring: " + subString);
            result = result + subString;
        }
        return result;
    }
```

It looks like this approach is not correct at all, because when I create a substring and the **i** index is greater than the **j**, the program goes in exception.

Is there a way to avoid this error?

Comment: My first observation is that your random generator isn't random.  Create the instance of `Random` once, outside of the loop, and re-use the same instance.  Otherwise all iterations of the loop are likely to generate the same random number.  Aside from that, how is `i` ever greater than `j`?  When you debug your code, what is the exact exception and what are the values being used?  Where did you get those values?  If you're trying to get a substring that exceeds the size of the string then just check that size before trying to get the substring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Substring(Int32, Int32) extracts a substring of length j starting from index i, which will break once i+j >= input.Length - i is true.

Example: Substring(2,2) applied to "ABCDEF" should return "CD". In your specific case it would be possible to have something like Substring(4,5) throwing an Exception since the String does not have enough elements.
At some point this loop will always cause an exception.

More details on the use of Substring can be found here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=netcore-3.1

Some things you can fix:

- Generate a random number in 1 to input.Length - i instead of 1 to input.Length
- Set i = i + j - 1 instead of i = j - 1

Algorithm:

1. Step

- i = 0
- Randomly roll j in 0 to (input.Length-1)
- Output j first letters starting from index i.
- Set i = i + j - 1

2. Step

- i = j
- Randomly roll j in 0 to (input.Length-1 - i)
- Output j first letters starting from index i.
- Set i = i + j - 1

3. Continue

Comment: Thanks, your suggestion was very helpful!